# starting application in rc.d causes terminal to freeze

Tags: init.d, openwrt, rc.d

I have a application which uses stdin and stdout. I wish this application to start running as soon as possible after all the background daemons are running.

I am using openwrt on an embedded system, using scp and serial to communicate with it.

I created an init.d script which just starts the application, with start=99.

When I boot up the device, after it reaches the terminal, it just hangs on the shell in the serial, I can however connect via scp. nut in either case the application hasn't started.

Is there a correct way to start an application which uses stdin and stdout so that it will start corrected after the OS has finished booting up?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use stdin for a terminal, because it blocks the single-mode runlevel, say, its waiting for the user to input at its tty. You can use stdin from any other non-terminal software application.

But why you are using terminal as user input?